# Public IP Address and Virtual Network Gateway failing to be createdin an Azure Trial account

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I purchased a one month Azure Trial account.

But I am not able to create a Public IP Address or a Virtual Network gateway.

Please help

Comment: You'll need to share more details around what Azure service you're attempting to deploy, how you're deploying(via Azure Portal or Azure PowerShell or Azure CLI, etc), what error you're facing and anything else that can help us figure out what the real issue is.

Comment: If you can supply more details (such as how did you create, location, error massage and etc) in this question,  I believe we can help you to resolve this issue.